# jqplot axis rendering : a.jqplot.CanvasFontRenderer is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, html, jqplot

I am trying to render the Y-axis label rotated 90 degree. Quoting the jqplot example

> By including the "jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js" and "jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js" plugins, you can render label text directly onto canvas elements.

Here is the error i get from Firebug

> TypeError: a.jqplot.CanvasFontRenderer is not a constructor

Here is my whole code

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.jqplot.css" />
                <!--Jquery Base Library 2.0.3 -->
        <script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
                <!-- jqPlot Libraro -->
        <script src="jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
                <!-- More jqplot file -->
        <script src="jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js"></script>
        <!-- example jqplot file -->
        <script src="test.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body style="margin:0px; padding-left:50px; padding-right:50px;" >
            <div style="padding-left: 20px; padding-right:20px; background-color:#FF7519;">
                <div id="chart" style="height:300px;width:800px; "></div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is test.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
  var cosPoints = [];
  for (var i=0; i<2*Math.PI; i+=0.1){
     cosPoints.push([i, Math.cos(i)]);
  }
  var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart', [cosPoints], {
      series:[{showMarker:false}],
 axes:{
        xaxis:{
          label:'Some X Label',
          labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
        },
        yaxis:{
          label:'Some Y Label',
          labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
        }
      }
  });
});
```

I am clueless, I don't understand what I am doing wrong since I am following the basic tutorial of this API. Thank you for your time

Comment: match your text renderer file with the file from this link: http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.js

Comment: i think you should  be using $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer to get your ticks rotated. Example: http://www.jqplot.com/tests/rotated-tick-labels.php

Comment: I did a wget of the file you linked me and now it is working. I am so confuse but thanks. May you answer the question so i can accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

match your text renderer file with the file from this link: [jqplot.com/deploy/dist/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.js](http://jqplot.com/deploy/dist/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.js)

I think this is the correct file and it has the `jqplot.CanvasFontRenderer` inside it. Maybe your file doesn't have that

Comment: This link is broken. can u advise where can I find the file?

Comment: CanvasFontRenderer.js can be found in jqPlot distribution files under the plugins directory.